# Can Apache Ignite work without H2 library?

Tags: java, h2

I found this sentence in the 2.14.0 release note:

Calcite-based SQL engine is now independent of H2-based SQL engine and doesn't require 'ignite-indexing' module and H2 to be in classpath anymore.

However when I start a simplest Ignite object, it gives error saying class not found for org.h2.value.ValueByte, am I missing anything.

Due to the security vulnerability of H2, all my Ignite applications were forced to stop at work I thought the version 2.14.0 allows me to get rid of H2. Anybody can give me an idea if I can have my apps running without H2?

Thanks

I manage my dependency with gradle,

```
implementation fiels('/myfolder/apache-ignite/2.14.0/libs/ignite-core-2.14.0.jar')
implementation fiels('/myfolder/apache-ignite/2.14.0/libs/cache-api-1.0.0.jar')
implementation fiels('/myfolder/apache-ignite/2.14.0/libs/annotations-16.0.3.jar')
implementation fiels('/myfolder/apache-ignite/2.14.0/libs/ignite-spring/ignite-spring-2.14.0.jar')
implementation fiels('/myfolder/apache-ignite/2.14.0/libs/ignite-indexing/ignite-indexing-2.14.0.jar')
```

this is how my code looks like:

```
TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder tcMp = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
spi.setIpFinder(tcMp);
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
cfg.setClentMode(false);
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
Ignite ignite=Ignition.start(cfg)
```

it failes at last line "Ignition.start(cfg);

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies?  What code is running that produces this error?

Comment: Edit your question with your code.  As you have surely noticed, there is no space to add it in here in the comments.

Comment: just updated the post with dependency and code

Answer (score 0):

Replace ignite-indexing-2.14.0.jar with ignite-calcite-2.14.0.jar